# creating a bipartite graph in igraph

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I'm trying to create a bipartite graph using igraph, but I'm getting an error message saying that I need to supply a 'types' argument. How do I do this if the types are the same on each side? i.e I want a node on each side that is 'off', 'low' etc. I've given some example code below.

```
from <- c('off','low','medium','low','strong','off','low')
to <- c('medium','low','strong','off','low','off','low' )
frequency <- c(20,12,5,1,41,40,2)
df <- as.matrix(cbind (from, to))
```

Comment: Could you please include the statement you used to try to make a graph, even though it did not work.  It will help specify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also,  did you mean to have low -> low twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *define* the types of the nodes by which of the two groups they are in.   Also,  you cannot have two nodes with the same ID.  However, you can put the same label on multiple nodes. I think that is what you want,  so here is a graph that has two nodes labeled "off",  two nodes labeled "low", etc.  The default layout did not emphasize the bipartite nature that I think you wanted, so I offer a different layout. Is this what you wanted?

```
EL = c(1,7,2,6,3,8,2,5,4,6,1,5,2,6)
types = rep(0:1, each=4)
g = make_bipartite_graph(types, EL, directed = TRUE)
g = set_vertex_attr(g, "label", value = rep(c('off','low','medium', 'strong'), 2))
LO = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,4), 
    nrow=8, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
plot(g, layout = LO)
```

[image: Bipartite]